# Java Swing Removing Jpanel while clicking on Jbutton which is present in that jpanel which I want to remove

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a GUI using Netbeans and my question is "how to remove the jpanel"...the hierarchical order as it is present Jframe->Jscrollpane->Jpanel->Jbutton. By clicking on the Jbutton I want to remove all components of the jpanel including the Jbutton(on which I am clicking) and the panel itself. Please do help.Urgent.THanks in advance

-Sayantan

```
private void b4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
final JPanel jp;
JTextField tf,of1,of2,xf,yf;
int i=1;
int m=(int)sp3.getValue();
JButton jb;
jp=new JPanel();
//jp.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
 DesignGridLayout layout = new DesignGridLayout(jp); 
  jsp2.getViewport().add(jp);  
   while(i<=m){
     tf=new JTextField(5);
     of1=new JTextField(5);
     of2=new JTextField(5);
    layout.row().grid(new JLabel("Type:")).indent(9).add(tf).grid(new     JLabel("Length:")).indent().add(of1).grid(new JLabel("Breadth:")).indent().add(of2).empty();
     fields1.add(tf);
     fields1.add(of1);
      fields1.add(of2);        
       xf=new JTextField(5);
     yf=new JTextField(5);
  layout.row().grid(new JLabel("X-axis:")).indent(9).add(xf).grid(new JLabel("Y-axis:")).indent().add(yf).empty(2);
      fields1.add(xf);
      fields1.add(yf);
      i++;
  }
  jb=new JButton("Submit");
  jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
        for(JTextField field: fields1){
        String s=field.getText();
        lbr.setText(lbr.getText()+s);
        }
         lb3.setVisible(false);
       sp3.setVisible(false);
        b4.setVisible(false);
       //jp.setVisible(false);
       //jp.removeAll();
      // jp.revalidate();

      //jp.repaint();

      // jsp2.remove(jp);
      //jsp2.revalidate();
      //jsp2.repaint();
      }
    });
    layout.emptyRow();
    layout.row().right().add(jb);
   jp.revalidate();
   jp.repaint();
   // jsp2.revalidate();
   //jsp2.repaint();
   }
```

Note: I am using DesignGridLayout package.

Comment: You could more that sample code much simpler.

Comment: What is currently happening (or not happening?) Tell us what your current result is and we can better help.

Comment: Who is teaching these weird user interface concepts?

Comment: hahaha @gilbert... I am facing while making this interface by own

Comment: @steve: if I am using jpanel.renoveAll(); only the jbutton is getting removed and everything remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ScratchSpace {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        panel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        panel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Kill me") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                panel.removeAll();
                panel.revalidate();
                panel.repaint();
            }
        }));

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: what about removing the panel itself? @steve

Comment: Design Grid layout is hindering it to perform...i am getting this err:"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Do not use this method
 at net.java.dev.designgridlayout.DesignGridLayoutManager.removeLayoutComponent(DesignGridLayoutManager.java:122"

Comment: With DesignGridLayout, you are not allowed to add or remove components directly to the panel; you must use DesignGridLayout API for that. DesignGridLayout doesn't make it possible to remove components once they've been added, but you may `hide()` rows, or groups of rows (`RowGroup`) if you need.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to remove all components of the jpanel including the Jbutton(on which I am clicking) and the panel itself.

Then you need code something like:

```
JButton button = (JButtton)event.getSource();
JPanel grandparent = button.getParent().getParent();
grandparent.removeAll();
grandparent.revalidate();
grandparent.repaint();
```

Although I question any code where I see a `removeAll()`. You might look into using a [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: where to use your code? @camickr I have made comment to removeAll() since its not happening.

Comment: Because you said you want to remove the button and the panel. `not happening` doesn't help. Post your SSCCE that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: When you don't know a term you can always search the web. Why wait 2 hours for me to reply to the question?

Comment: A SSCCE should be posted with your question when you ask your question.